# C++, Array of pointers, pointing to entries in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, linked-list

I currently have a linked list that has been created and needs an array of pointers to each item in the list so that it can be sorted and manipulated.

```
using namespace std;

struct Node {
 float tries;
 float vals;
 Node* next;
 Node* prev;
};

class doList {
 public:
  doList(float attempts[], float values[], int numElements) {

    Node* current;
    current = new Node;
    current->tries = attempts[0];
    current->vals = values[0];
    current->prev = NULL;
    head = current;
    tail = current;

    for (int d = 1; d < numElements; d++) {
      current = new Node;
      current->tries = attempts[d];
      current->vals = values[d];
      current->prev = tail;
      tail->next = current;
      tail = current;
      if (d == (numElements - 1)) {
        tail->next = NULL;
      }
    }
    arrayPointers = new Node*[numElements];

  }

  private:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    Node** arrayPointers;
  };
```

I tried to use a private element to make the array of pointers and allocated space for it, but not sure how to work with it besides that. Have to do it without including any other options.

**EDIT**
Sorry I was not clear enough. I am confused on how to use the array of pointers to the linked list. I need help figuring out how to store the nodes in an array of pointers. Essentially I need to have an array where the elements in the array point to entries in the list.

Comment: What is your question?
Btw, please also state what your target is. If you want to use a double linked list, maybe you should take a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Comment: You, probably, want to store the nodes in an array, instead of free store - instead of pointers you will have indexes into array.

Comment: Create the array first, store the pointers in it as you create them. (I'm not convinced that this simplifies anything and suspect that there's been a misunderstanding somewhere.)

Comment: Your question is indeed unclear. Please, as a new user, first take the [tour] and read [ask]. Welcome to Stack Overflow nonetheless!

Comment: I tried to add more clarification. I currently don't understand how to make an array that has elements that point to entries in the list. I understand the logic behind it, but not sure how to put it in terms of C++

Comment: I think you are looking at the list backwards. You create your list as normal, joining nodes with `->next` and `->prev` pointers. You can also add a pointer to each node to your array that would allow easy sorting of your list for output purposes without having to re-wire your list each time your wanted to change the sort. (you can simply sort the pointer array based on whatever criteria you have, e.g. `tries` or `vals` ascending/descending, etc..) You are allocating for each node in your list to create the list, just assign each pointer to your array.

Comment: I doubt this is what you are asked for. Anyhow: Move the array allocation at the begining of constructor. Fill each element in for, after you allocate the node: arrayPointers[d] = current; Do the same for head: arrayPointers[0]...

Comment: Whatever you want to achieve, I'm pretty sure you don't need an array. Because you have to choose between an array or a list. Now, if your final goal is to sort, you can still come up with an algorithm to sort a list, traversing the list sequentially, comparing each item to the next and swapping them if needed...

Comment: Why do you have a class named after a verb (`do`)? Shouldn't that be a function?

Comment: @ZDF I see what you're saying, that makes sense.

Comment: @user2217 Are you trying to implement heap sort?

Comment: @ZDF I have to sort the linked list and then be able to eliminate some of the linked list elements in the constructor based on data. Then I have to add data and change data of the elements of the list using the array of pointers.

Comment: _" I have to sort the linked list and..."_ Sorting the list means the list is already constructed, so what means _"...eliminate some of the linked list elements in the constructor..."_ Most likely you misunderstood the requirement. Check with your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create the array beforehand and store the pointer to each element at creation time.

```
doList(float attempts[], float values[], int numElements) {

    arrayPointers = new Node*[numElements];
    Node* current;
    current = new Node;
    current->tries = attempts[0];
    current->vals = values[0];
    current->prev = NULL;
    head = current;
    tail = current;
    arrayPointers[0] = current;

    for (int d = 1; d < numElements; d++) 
    {
      current = new Node;
      current->tries = attempts[d];
      current->vals = values[d];
      current->prev = tail;
      tail->next = current;
      tail = current;
      arraypointers[d] = current;
      if (d == (numElements - 1)) 
      {
        tail->next = NULL;
      }
    }
  }
```